# Laravel static Model is not returning error

Tags: laravel, static

I have this Model `UserSetting.php`:

```php
class UserSetting extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'name', 'setting_value'];

    public static function set($user_id, $name, $value)
    {

        if (!User::find($user_id)) {
            return error('NoForeign_User');
        }

        self::updateOrCreate(
            ['user_id' => $user_id, 'name' => $name],
            ['setting_value' => $value]
        );
    }
}
```

And I want to use it this way inside `UserSettingController.php`:

```php
public function user(Request $request)
{
    Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'user_id'       => 'required|int',
        'name'          => 'required|string',
        'setting_value' => 'required|string',
    ], $this->messages)->validate();

    // HERE IS THE CALL
    UserSetting::set($request->user_id, $request->name, $request->setting_value);

    return saved();
}
```

I need to call `UserSetting` statically but NOT with a **return**:

```
return UserSetting::set(...)
```

But when the static function gets to the `if(!User::find($user_id))` it carries on and shows the `saved()` helper instead of the `return error('NoForeign_User')`

While if I do it with a return `return UserSetting::set(...)` it correctly shows the error.

Is this correct? Do I have any other option other then **returning** the static class?

**EDIT**:

My `error()` function is this:

```php
function error($message, $code = 422)
{
    $response = ['message' => $message];
    if ($errors) {
        $response += [
            'errors' => $errors,
        ];
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => $message,
    ], $code);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't check the result that is being returned when calling the static method, then for sure the program will continue to execute the next line which is the `saved()` method in your case.

In order to stop execution a better approach is to throw an exception which will propagate to the `Exception` handler and stop the function execution.

So instead of this:

```
if (!User::find($user_id)) {
    return error('NoForeign_User');
}
```

try this:

```
if (!User::find($user_id)) {
    throw new \Exception('NoForeign_User');
}
```

or yet another and the best approach in my opinion that I just remembered is to simply use the `findOrFail` function:

```
User::findOrFail($user_id);
```

This will also throw an exception if the user has not been found.